# mysql statement to count sends

Tags: python, mysql

I have this `mysql` table

```
id | sender | file_id
1  | A      | 376482734627836
2  | B      | 67387648327648726
3  | B      | 8734682346287346
4  | A      | 78623186347812
5  | A      | 278618762378
6  | C      | 287628681682
7  | A      | 8389479247
```

I'm not good on "making a good sql statement", but I'd like to output the SENDER who have more entries

```
print("the user: "+user+" is the winner with "+sends+" sends!")
```

how would be the simple way for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you could use

```
select sender 
from my_table 
group by sender 
order by count(*) desc limit 1
```